# Python Script unable to identify files in Usage

Tags: python, file, scripting

The overall idea is to identify the presence of an input command file, use the commands stored to operate on text files that have the information stored in them and output based on the number of records selected.

The code however consistently stops at the first exit after the if statement. I'm a little lost with this one. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import random
import shlex

#parameter check

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage: ./filemaker <INPUTCOMMANDFILE> <OUTPUTFILE> <RECORDCOUNT>")
    exit(1)

#store parameters in usable variables
filemaker = sys.argv[0]
inputFile = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]
recordcount = sys.argv[3]

try:
    recordcount = int(recordcount)
except:
    print("Error")
    exit(1)


try:
    inputFile =open(inputFile, 'r')
except:
    print("Error with opening input file")
    exit(1)

try:
    outputFile = open(outputfile, 'w')

except:
    print("Error with opening output file")
    exit(1)


#slurping commands into a commands list

cmdList = inputFile.readlines()
header = shlex.split(cmdList[0])
#declaring dictionary
randomFiles = {}

#conditional statements
if header[0] == "HEADER":
    outputFile.write(header[1].decode('string_escape'))

#slurping files into randomFiles
for i in range(len(cmdList)):
    cmd = shlex.split(cmdList[i])
    if cmd[0] == "FILEWORD":
        inFile = open(cmd[2], 'r')
        randomFiles[cmd[2]] = inFile.readlines()
inFile.close()

#printing randomFiles


randomData = {}
for i in range(recordcount):
    randomData = {}
    for c in range(len(cmdList)):
        cmd = shlex.split(cmdList[c])
        if cmd[0] == "STRING":
            outputFile.write(cmd[1].decode('string_escape'))
        if cmd[0] == "FILEWORD":
            label = cmd[1]
            if label in randomData:
                print ("Error - key exists")
                exit(1)
            else:
                randWord = randomFiles[cmd[2]][random.randint(0, len(randomFiles[cmd[2]])-1)]
                randWord = randWord.rstrip()
                randomData[cmd[1]] = randWord
                outputFile.write(randomData[cmd[1]])
        if cmd[0] == "NUMBER":
            label = cmd[1]
            minNum = int(cmd[2])
            maxNum = int(cmd[3])
            if label in randomData:
                print ("Error - key exists")
                exit(1)
            else:
                randNum = random.randint(minNum, maxNum)
                randomData[cmd[1]] = str(randNum)
                outputFile.write(randomData[cmd[1]])
        if cmd[0] == "REFER":
            label = cmd[1]
            outputFile.write(randomData[label])
exit(0)
```

> The command line being run is simply the directory of the file so foldername ./filemaker (the name of the script)

Comment: is it exiting in the parameter check itself...??

Comment: Yes it is. It immediately prints  and exits the code

Comment: can you update the question with the exact command line argument which you are passing.?

Comment: If you print out `sys.argv` you'll see that the first argument is always the Python file that you executed. This means that if you follow your usage example you will have 5 items in sys.argv not 4.